# SSI included in PHP as template not working

Tags: php, apache, templates, ssi, templatepower

I am using [Ganglia-web-frontend](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/) which is written in PHP. It uses template files to add personal headers/footers. I want to use an SSI set of pages that I have written, but the SSI code is not interpreted by apache.

more clearly, ganglia uses `$tpl = new TemplatePower( template("$header.tpl") );` to include my header template file. In my header.tpl file I put : `<!--#include virtual="/include/header.shtml" -->` which is my included file (and which works perfectly with my personal pages/scripts).

If look to the HTML code that I get in firefox (ctrl+U) I see that apache has included the SSI zone `<!--#include virtual="/include/header.shtml" -->` as a commentary, and has not interpreded it.

I suppose there is something to do with the order in which things are interpreded/executed, but I cannot find the way to doing it work. Does anyone have an idea? I have root access to apache configuration too, if needed.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Following Sasha's suggestions I have tried to add

```
AddType text/html .tpl 
AddHandler server-parsed .tpl
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .tpl
```

to */etc/apache2/httpd.conf* but this does not help. I don't get it...

EDIT 2 :

I guess it is maybe a problem with PHP [TemplatePower](http://templatepower.codocad.com/) module. But I cannot get it work. I have tried adding also `$tpl->assignInclude( "header", "./header.tpl" );` in ganglia sources but this does not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is Apache configured to preprocess `.tpl` files as Server-Side Includes? If not, it will ignore SSI directives in those files.

The section on ['Enabling Server-Side Includes' in the mod_include documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html#enabling) has details on how to configure this. You'll need to ensure that `.tpl` is present in the `AddType` and `AddOutputFilter` directives.

Comment: Thanks for your anser, I have tried to add `AddType text/html .tpl
AddHandler server-parsed .tpl
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .tpl` to *httpd.conf* but this does not change. I get the same result...

Comment: @Danduk82: You should really push forward `AddOutputFilter` because that's most easy to integrate. Ensure your PHP's scripts outputs is going through the apache output filter. I didin't see it here when I answered and also I wasn't aware SSI works therein, but I know how these work, so you should really look for that.

Comment: In fact I had to add `AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .php` so that it gets correctly piped by Apache. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You are loading the template as `TemplatePower` template. So not apache is hosting that .tpl file but your script is, through that `TemplatePower` object.

Therefore this is out of scope of the content-handlers and action-handlers of apache.

*if* you're running PHP as apache SAPI you can make use of the [`virtual()`](http://php.net/virtual) function.

You could then extend the templating engine to interprete those include virtual SSI commands and invoke the `virtual()` function.

So the key point here really is that in the end Apache needs to execute the shtml template via a subrequest.